Luminosity distance in a FRW Universe
In the following presentation:
https://www.slac.stanford.edu/econf/C0307282/lec_notes/pinto/pinto.pdf
we have the relation for the luminosity distance in a FRW universe:
\begin{aligned}
D_L & =\frac{3}{H_0}(1+z) \kappa_0^{-1 / 2} \\
& S\left\{\kappa_0^{1 / 2} \int_0^z\left[\sum_i \Omega_i(1+z)^{3\left(1+w_i\right)}-\kappa_0(1+z)^2\right]^{-1 / 2} \mathrm{d} z^{\prime}\right\}
\end{aligned}
How is this derived? Is there any textbook where i can found the detailed derivation?
Thanks

These  notes seem to contain the analyisis, but start from a rather high level mathematically.https://user-web.icecube.wisc.edu/~halzen/notes/week1-3.pdf
